# jQuery to show an open sibling while closing the previously opened sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an FAQ setup. When a question is clicked, I toggle the corresponding answer (`.sibling`) to appear. That works fine and another click on the same question, closes that sibling. All good.
What I want to do instead is to make the currently open sibling toggle closed when another question gets clicked. New to JavaScript so my experiments have fallen flat. How should I modify my JavaScript to make this possible. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".answer").hide();
  $(".question").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".answer").toggle(300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div class="question">Question 1</div>
      <div class="answer">Answer to Question 1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="question">Question 2</div>
      <div class="answer">Answer to Question 2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="question">Question 3</div>
      <div class="answer">Answer to Question 3</div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to hide any `.answer` element on click.

Although, if you simply hide all answers, clicking to close the current one will close it, then re-open it.

So you need to first determine which answer is the correct sibling object (set as the sibling variable below), then compare it to each of the answer objects using jQuery's `.each()` method, and only close those that are not the target sibling.  To do this you can compare the sibling object to each answer object using jQuery's `.is()` method in a conditional.

```js
$(function () {
    $(".answer").hide();
    $(".question").click(function ()
    {
      var sibling = $(this).next('.answer');
      
       $(".answer").each(function() {
          var answer = $(this);
          if (!answer.is(sibling)) {
              $(this).hide(300);
          }
       })
       $(this).siblings(".answer").toggle(300);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <div class="question">Question 1</div>
            <div class="answer">Answer to Question 1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="question">Question 2</div>
            <div class="answer">Answer to Question 2</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="question">Question 3</div>
            <div class="answer">Answer to Question 3</div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay... I knew it had to be simple as all hell. Works fine but... if I click on the same question again (say, to manually close it without selecting another question) it immediately pops back open - like in a loop. This isn't necessarily a real problem but, what would stop that?

Comment: Perfecto... exactly what I needed. The edits you made allowed everything to work as needed and I even applied this to other areas of my app. Thanks much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, depending on how complicated your FAQ gets. Assuming you only ever have that one level deep of questions and answers, you could simply close all the answers on a click like so:

```
$(function () {
    $(".answer").hide();
    $(".question").click(function ()
    {
        $(this).closest("ol").find(".answer").hide(300);
        $(this).siblings(".answer").toggle(300);
    });
});
```